# Wifi Shield and Motor Shield working together

Tags: c, arduino, wifi, led

I am currently involved in a project which needs to have 4 led's and one stepper motor to be turned on/off independently over wifi.

Just to mention Im using an Uno r3, official Wifi shield and official motor shield.

I have the 4 led's working on pins A2-A5 or in my code pins (16-19) leaving free all digital pins and have set up my stepper motor to pins 9,8,6,5. When i go to the ip address i can turn off/on each LED independently but with the stepper motor it either judders and does not move or nothing at all.

I have posted my code so far below, would really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks

```
/*
  WiFi Web Server LED Blink

 A simple web server that lets you blink an LED via the web.
 This sketch will print the IP address of your WiFi Shield (once connected)
 to the Serial monitor. From there, you can open that address in a web browser
 to turn on and off the LED on pin 9.

 This example is written for a network using WPA encryption. For 
 WEP or WPA, change the Wifi.begin() call accordingly.

 Circuit:
 * WiFi shield attached
 * LED attached to pin 9

 created 25 Nov 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

char ssid[] = "username";      //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "password";   // your network password
int keyIndex = 0;  
int delaylegnth = 7;
int state = 0;
int x = 0;
// your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial communication
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode
  pinMode(17, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode
  pinMode(18, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode
  pinMode(19, OUTPUT);      // set the LED pin mode

    //establish motor direction toggle pins
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //CH A -- HIGH = forwards and LOW = backwards???
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT); //CH B -- HIGH = forwards and LOW = backwards???

  //establish motor brake pins
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) CH A
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) CH B

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present"); 
    while(true);        // don't continue
  } 

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);                   // print the network name (SSID);

    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  server.begin();                           // start the web server on port 80
  printWifiStatus();                        // you're connected now, so print out the status

}


void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";  // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    String currentLine2 = ""; 
    String currentLine3 = "";
    String currentLine4 = "";  
    String currentLine5 = ""; 
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {  
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:    
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();

            // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 4 on<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 4 off<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/A\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 5 on<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/B\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 5 off<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/C\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 6 on<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/D\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 6 off<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/E\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 on<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/F\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 off<br>");
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/G\">here</a> turn the Stepper<br>");
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;         
          } 
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
            currentLine2 = "";
            currentLine3 = "";
            currentLine4 = "";
            currentLine5 = "";
          }
        }     
        else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;
          currentLine2 += c;
          currentLine3 += c;
          currentLine4 += c;
          currentLine5 += c;
        }

        // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
          digitalWrite(16, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
          digitalWrite(16, LOW);                // GET /L turns the LED off
        }
        if (currentLine2.endsWith("GET /A")) {
          digitalWrite(17, HIGH);               // GET /A turns the LED on
        }
        if (currentLine2.endsWith("GET /B")) {
          digitalWrite(17, LOW);                // GET /B turns the LED off
        }
          if (currentLine3.endsWith("GET /C")) {
          digitalWrite(18, HIGH);               // GET /A turns the LED on
        }
        if (currentLine3.endsWith("GET /D")) {
          digitalWrite(18, LOW);                // GET /B turns the LED off
        }
          if (currentLine4.endsWith("GET /E")) {
          digitalWrite(19, HIGH);               // GET /A turns the LED on
        }
        if (currentLine4.endsWith("GET /F")) {
          digitalWrite(19, LOW);                // GET /B turns the LED off
        }
           }

          if (currentLine5.endsWith("GET /G")) { //stepper motor
//     for(int x; x < 500; x++) {

//  state=digitalRead(0);
//  if (state == LOW){

  digitalWrite(9, LOW);  //ENABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); //DISABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);   //Sets direction of CH A
  analogWrite(A0, 255);   //Moves CH A

//  }

//  else{

  delay(delaylegnth);

  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  //DISABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, LOW); //ENABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(6, LOW);   //Sets direction of CH B
  analogWrite(A1, 255);   //Moves CH B

  delay(delaylegnth);

  digitalWrite(9, LOW);  //ENABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); //DISABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(5, LOW);   //Sets direction of CH A
  analogWrite(A0, 255);   //Moves CH A

  delay(delaylegnth);

  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  //DISABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, LOW); //ENABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);   //Sets direction of CH B
  analogWrite(A1, 255);   //Moves CH B

  delay(delaylegnth);

//     }
//     }

      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disonnected");
  }
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  // print where to go in a browser:
  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);
}
```